# Update table where SELECT id From tableB not exists

Tags: mysql

I'd like to find a way to update a table if the value doesn't exist in another table.

The (simplified) versions of my three tables:

```
Table_A         Table_B                     Table_C
                                            (idA + typ = PRIMARY key)
idA | name      id | idA | typ | amm        idA | typ | name | total
10  | Dodo      1  | 10  |  1  |   1        10  |  1  | Dodo |   2
                2  | 10  |  1  |   1        10  |  2  | Dodo |   4
                3  | 10  |  2  |   2        10  |  3  | Dodo |   6
                4  | 10  |  2  |   2        10  |  4  | Dodo |   8
                5  | 10  |  3  |   3
                6  | 10  |  3  |   3
                7  | 10  |  4  |   4 *
                8  | 10  |  4  |   4 *
```

I use this query to update `Table_C`

```
INSERT INTO Table_C 
    ( idA , name , typ , total )
SELECT 
    tX.idA , tX.name , tX.typ , tX.total
FROM (
     SELECT tA.idA , tA.name,
           tB.typ , tB.total
     FROM table_A `tA`

     LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT 
            idA , typ , SUM(amm) total
            FROM table_B `tB`                 <<here
            GROUP BY idA,typ                 
         ) tB
        ON tA.idA = tB.idA
        WHERE tA.idA = 10
) tX
                                              <<here
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   idA = tX.idA,
   name = tX.name,
   typ = tX.typ,
   total = tX.total
```

This works fine. But now I remove `typ 4` from `Table_B` and I update again.

**The question is**: Is there a way in the above query to set the values (or at least `total`) of the missing `typ 4` (and any other missing types) to zero? So the result would be:

```
Table_C
idA | typ | name | total
10  |  1  | Dodo |   2
10  |  2  | Dodo |   4
10  |  3  | Dodo |   6
10  |  4  | Dodo |   0  <<<<
```

I tried adding at the `<<here`

```
   LEFT JOIN table_C tC
   ON ?.idA = tC.idA AND ?.typ = tC.typ 
   WHERE tC.typ IS NULL
```

(where ? = either tB or tX) but with no result.

[Here is a Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e2F1HXdiyyvLBQGoCkvhhL/4)

**EDIT**

Don't know if there is an easier way to do it, but in the end I solved it by adding this piece just after `WHERE tA.idA = 10`:

```
UNION ALL (
    SELECT idA, "", typ , 0
    FROM table_C tC
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT 
            idA, typ
            FROM table_B tB
            WHERE tC.idA = tB.idA AND 
                tC.typ = tB.typ
            GROUP BY idA,typ
        )
    AND idA=10
    GROUP BY idA,typ
)
```

Comment: Have the query not given error for union query you write after your query because it is in insert statement?Though i feel this will not solve the problem because to get the sum 0 you need atleast  the record for typ=4 having amm=0

Comment: No it is working fine. The `UNION` is inside the `FROM (...)`, right at the end, so no problem. I've made an updated [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rT8ph3nhw82VG1K8o9c9A9/2)